# Are you secure when using Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I have a .Net MVC application. I use Asp.net Identity for login and roles.

Every controller I have is decorated with [Authorize]

I have not done anything else in the code to protect the application.

Is there anything Else that must be done in ordet to protect the site? And im not takling protection of the webserver. Only the website.

Thanks

Comment: Yes... Make sure you're not vulnerable to SQL Injection, XSS, CSRF, etc, etc... Have a read through the [OWASP  top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)

Comment: Interesting article about this here: http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/state-microsoft-security-aspnet-identity-20    and also here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add MVC's anti-forgery support, this basically writes a unique value to an HTTP-only cookie and then the same value is written to the form. When the page is submitted, an error is raised if the cookie value doesn't match the form value.

It's important to note that the feature prevents cross site request forgeries.

How to use it: 
Decorate every controller action used to post data with this: `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and add the unique value to your form posting the data by adding the following to your form `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

Comment: I will look into that. My app architecture is one database pr. Customer. And each customer will have 1-5 users. And they pay to use it so its not a site every one can sign up to. So if they write sql-injection or cross site request its only them self they are hacking.. But again its easy just to decorate, just in case... The way I made it now is that i have a customer object, and that customer have a one-to-one relationship with a user object, and that user object have all the properties regarding asp identity. Is that the way to go? Or should i just put them on the customer object?

Comment: If the site is online and it accepts input from users such as a login form which is exposed to the public most likely, it will be exposed to all sorts of hacks, including xss, etc.

Comment: @user2999692 Did I answer your question: "Is there anything Else that must be done in ordet to protect the site?"